# Issue instantiating a custom java (nio) file system

Tags: java, nio

I am working on creating a custom file system based on the [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/io/fsp/filesystemprovider.html). I have created a `CustomFileSystemProvider` (and other CustomFileSystem classes) and overridden the required methods. The `getScheme()` method of the `CustomFileSystemProvider` returns the string "myfs". 
However when I try to test this file system with the following code

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem(URI.create("myfs://a_remote_resource"), env);
```

I get an error

```
java.nio.file.ProviderNotFoundException: Provider "myfs" not found
at java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:341)
at java.nio.file.FileSystems.newFileSystem(FileSystems.java:276)
at Tester.main(Tester.java:30)
```

I don't see my custom file system in the list returned by `FileSystemProvider.installedProviders()`. I am not sure what I need to register a custom FS as an "installedProvider".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `FileSystemProvider` is loaded as explained in the Javadoc for [FileSystems](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystems.html):

> Installed providers are loaded using the service-provider loading
>   facility defined by the ServiceLoader class. Installed providers are
>   loaded using the system class loader. If the system class loader
>   cannot be found then the extension class loader is used; if there is
>   no extension class loader then the bootstrap class loader is used.
>   Providers are typically installed by placing them in a JAR file on the
>   application class path or in the extension directory, the JAR file
>   contains a provider-configuration file named
>   java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider in the resource directory
>   META-INF/services, and the file lists one or more fully-qualified
>   names of concrete subclass of FileSystemProvider that have a zero
>   argument constructor

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Google auto-service](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/service)  for this:

Annotate your FileSystemProvider implementation class as follows:

```
@AutoService(FileSystemProvider.class)
```

Then you won't need to fiddle about with files in META-INF.

Answer (score -4):

It's a error URL.Change the URL to a standard url.You also can provide a analysiser.

> URL aURL = new URL("http://java.sun.com:80/docs/books/tutorial" +
>   "/index.html?name=networking#DOWNLOADING");
>
> System.out.println("protocol = " + aURL.getProtocol());
>
> System.out.println("authority = " + aURL.getAuthority());
>   System.out.println("host = " + aURL.getHost());
>
> System.out.println("port = " + aURL.getPort());
>
> System.out.println("path = " + aURL.getPath());
>
> System.out.println("query = " + aURL.getQuery());
>
> System.out.println("filename = " + aURL.getFile());
>
> System.out.println("ref = " + aURL.getRef());

result like ：

```
ut:ut:protocol = http
ut:ut:authority = localhost:8080
ut:ut:host = localhost
ut:ut:port = 8080
ut:ut:path = /UT2.0/login.action
ut:ut:query = null
ut:ut:filename = /UT2.0/login.action
ut:ut:ref = null
```

If you operate file by internet,choose a kind of a protocol such as RPC,socket...

Comment: The URI follows the standard [scheme:][//authority][path][?query][#fragment]`